# Roll n 3-sided dice (ABC). What's the probability of at least one A and two Bs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

Suppose you have n three-sided dice, with sides labelled A, B, C.
What is the probability of getting ABB among your dice (i.e. at least one A, at least two Bs)? Order is not important.

*(By bruteforcing it in Python, it would appear that the first few probabilities are likely as follows:*

*n=3: 3/3^3*

*n=4: 22/3^4*

*n=5: 105/3^5*

*n=6: 416/3^6*

*but I can't see how to derive a general formula. Is it some kind of cumulative multinomial horribleness or am I missing something obvious?)*

Comment: Each die has 3 sides and there are 3 dice so there are $3^3= 27$ possible outcomes, all equally likely.  Since there are only 3 dice, "at least one A, at least two Bs" means "exactly one A, exactly two Bs" but in any order so "ABB", "BAB", "BBA", three of the 27 outcomes so the probability is 3/27= 1/9.

Comment: @user247327 yes the case n=3 is trivial indeed. How about for other n?

Comment: OK I've solved it. Stand down, StackExchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation $A^{k}$ to mean $k$ $A$'s:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
|A^{1+} \cap B^{2+}| &=& |A^{1+}| + |B^{2+}| - |A^{1+}\cup B^{2+}| \\
&=& 3^n - |A^0| + 3^n - |B^0| - |B^1| - (3^n - |A^0\cap B^0| - |A^0\cap B^1|) \\
&=& 3^n - 2^n + 3^n - 2^n - n2^{n-1} - (3^n - 1 - n) \\
&=& 3^n - 2^{n+1} - n2^{n-1} + n + 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

So your probability is:

$$P(n) = \frac{3^n - 2^{n+1} - n2^{n-1} + n + 1}{3^n}$$